# Best way to do property aliasing?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm in a situation where it's necessary to be able to call a method on an object by two different names, and the shortest way I've found to do it is like this:

```
var c = {
    a : function() {console.log("called a!");}.
    b : function() {this.a();}
};
```

I was rather hoping there was something like this:

```
var c = {
    a,b : function() {console.log("called a!");}.
};
```

But my research thus far has not happened upon anything like that. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no good way to do this in JS using just one statement, but you can have it done inside a closure, which is what most JS modules do anyway.

```
var c = (function () {
    var a = function() {console.log("called a!");};
    return {
        'a': a,
        'b': a
    };
}());
```

Comment: This is perfect. I had no idea I could do this. In fact I'd really like to read more about this, but I'm not sure how...do you know what the term is for using the return statement in connection with a comma-separated series of method/property associations in JS?

Comment: @Aerovistae: It's just a function returning an object with properties. Though this looks like it's longer than your "shortest way".

Answer (score 6):

You can assign b later:

```
var c = {
    a : function() {console.log("called a!");}.
};

c.b = c.a;
```

Comment: Short and neat, but probably not the optimal organizational scheme. holding out for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a constructor function

```
function d(){
    this.a = this.b = function() {console.log("to c or not to c?");};
}

c = new d();
```

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/7Argh/1/).

Comment: rather `this.a = this.b = function() {console.log("called a!");}` yes?

Comment: My favorite solution so far. Precise and encapsulated.

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = new function() {
    this.a = this.b = function() {console.log("called a!");}.
};
```

Though it may look like it, `c` is not referencing a function, but rather a new object with the `a` and `b` properties.

Plus there's no additional namespace clutter.

If you need this to create multiple objects, then the named version makes more sense.